# Cannot compile c++ projects in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compilation, visual-studio-2013

I no longer can compile any c++ project. When i try to compile anything i get following errors:

> Error 101 error MSB4018: The "CL" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.CL.set_BrowseInformation(Boolean
>   value)    C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 341 5   ConsoleApplication
>
> Error 102 error MSB4026: The
>   "BrowseInformation=%(ClCompile.BrowseInformation)" parameter for the
>   "CL" task is invalid. C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 351 9   ConsoleApplication

Projects in other languages i.e C# are working fine.

Does anyone had similar problem to mine? What is the solution? I tried reinstall .Net framework and Visual Studio itself.

Comment: you may have something weird in your local register or environment. Have you tried with another fresh user account ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable browse information generation by adding flag /FR or /Fr. it might work for you.
To enable it you can follow below link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5a52hhk.aspx